# MS SQL - FULLTEXT INDEX - Which column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, full-text-search

I have some issues with FULLTEXT Index on MS SQL Server. I have created a simple solution below (please ignore obvious data design issues). I have started using full text index in my database and this has a lot of benefits over using LIKE with wildcards, especially in terms of speed on very big tables with multiple columns to search.

```
create fulltext catalog FullTextCatalog as default
select * from sys.fulltext_catalogs
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Books') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE  dbo.Books
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Books
(
BookID          INT IDENTITY(1,1),
BookTitle       NVARCHAR(255),
BookDescription NVARCHAR(1000),
BookCategory    NVARCHAR(255),
CONSTRAINT [PK_Books] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
BookID ASC
)
)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Books (BookTitle, BookDescription, BookCategory)
VALUES
('Book1', 'This is the first book in the series', 'Sport'),
('Book2', 'This is the second book in the series', 'Sport'),
('Book3', 'This is the third sport book in the series', 'Sport'),
('Book4', 'This is the NEW book in the series about nature', 'Nature')
GO

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON dbo.Books
(
BookTitle       LANGUAGE 'Neutral',
BookDescription LANGUAGE 'Neutral',
BookCategory    LANGUAGE 'Neutral'
)
KEY INDEX [PK_Books] ON ([FullTextCatalog], FILEGROUP [PRIMARY])
WITH (CHANGE_TRACKING = AUTO, STOPLIST = SYSTEM);
GO

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:03'

SELECT *
FROM dbo.Books
WHERE FREETEXT((BookTitle, BookDescription, BookCategory), 'sport')
```

One of my requirements is to know which column my search string was found in. So using the table above I need to know that the search term 'sport' was found in columns BookDescription and BookCategory for record 3 and only BookCategory for records 1 & 2. The code below is something I have worked out to search the index and although this almost accomplishes my aim it has many problems. Especially the fact that I need to search the index using LIKE and wildcards, this defeats the object of me using the fulltext index in the first place. Also LIKE will return different results if I'm looking for partial words (port) compared to FREETEXT.

```
SELECT  kw.*, c.name
FROM    sys.dm_fts_index_keywords_by_document(DB_ID(), OBJECT_ID('dbo.Books')) kw
JOIN    sys.all_columns c
ON      kw.column_id = c.column_id
WHERE   display_term like '%sport%'
AND     c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.Books')
ORDER BY kw.document_id, c.column_id
```

Does anyone else have any idea how I can find which columns the fulltext index located the search term?